# Send mail from oracle store procedure ,Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, email, oracle11g

I am trying  to send mail using utl_mail and for smtp server smtp.gmail.com with port 25 or 587.

If i use port 25,getting error,  must use STARTTLS command first and for 587 its going in an infinite loop.

my code snippet are below

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE TEST_UTL_MAIL AS 
BEGIN
  utl_mail.send(
   sender => 'xxx@gmail.com',
    recipients => 'xxx@gmail.com',
   subject => 'Testing utl_mail',
    message => 'The receipt of this email means'
 );
 EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
  raise_application_error(-20001,'The following error has occured: ' || sqlerrm);
   END;
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using? I _think_ 11.2.0.2 is the first version with TLS support for mail.

Comment: yes PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production

Comment: Then I think you'll have trouble making it work. Your mail server seems to demand TLS (secure) communication, and the database package does not support that until 11.2.0.2. There's more info [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/Oracle/A_5915-Extending-Oracle's-Email-functionality-with-PL-SQL-Authentication.html) if you search for TLS.

Comment: is there any better way to do this in my oracle version?

Comment: If you can change the settings on the mail server side, you could always disable TLS requirements for the IP number of the Oracle server until Oracle is updated when you can most likely turn it on again. Adding TLS support to `utl_mail` doesn't really seem feasible.

Comment: so i need to disable TLS for sender email addres?

Comment: I don't know if there also are _other_ requirements such as the sender logging in (which is talked about in the linked article in the comment above), but yes, at the least you need to somehow disable TLS for either the sender or the machine sending.

Comment: @ Joachim Isaksson thanks for your time,i will try and then get back with result

Answer (score 0):

You may have access control list issues. What is the error the code is reporting?
Also can you supply the output of this query (you'll need to supply the user parameter):
`SELECT host, lower_port, upper_port, acl,
     DECODE(
         DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CHECK_PRIVILEGE_ACLID(aclid, '&USER', 'connect'),
            1, 'GRANTED', 0, 'DENIED', null) privilege
     FROM dba_network_acls
;`